# No error but still not displaying an object in the scenery

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I have a scenery full of mountains and water developed in C. I want to add a Sun in the scenery. But the sun do not appears in the scenery. Attached below is my code. Please help me do this..

```
// Include files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include "gl/Glu.h"
#include "Gl/glut.h"
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

#include "resources.h"
#include "fovdemo.h"

// Global variables
HINSTANCE hInstance;
HWND hWnd;
HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
float cam_x, cam_y, cam_z;
float cam_yaw, cam_pitch;
float hfov, aspect;
int fovmode;
bool active;
static int useRGB = 1;
static int useLighting = 1;
static int useFog = 0;
static int useDB = 1;
static int useLogo = 0;
static int useQuads = 1;

static int tick = -1;
static int moving = 1;

#define GREY    0
#define RED     1
#define GREEN   2
#define BLUE    3
#define CYAN    4
#define MAGENTA 5
#define YELLOW  6
#define BLACK   7
static float lightPos[4] =
{2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0};

static float lightAmb[4] ={0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0};
static float lightDiff[4] ={0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0};
static float lightSpec[4] ={0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0};
static float fogColor[4] ={0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
static float fogIndex[1] ={0.0};

static unsigned char shadowPattern[128] =
{
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,  /* 50% Grey */
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55,
  0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55
};



// Function prototypes
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL CALLBACK DummyProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM) { return false; }

float GetTime ()
{
    return (float)GetTickCount() / 1000.0f;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// WINMAIN FUNCTION
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    // Copy instance handle into global variable
    hInstance = hThisInstance;

    // Check for previous instance
    if (hPrevInstance)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Sorry, you can only start one instance of this program at a time.", "Can't Start Program", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Register window class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpszClassName = "FovDemoClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0;
        // Create main window
    hWnd = CreateWindow("FovDemoClass", "Fov Demo", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    //Sun Code
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(200, 300, 0.0f);
    static const int circle_points = 100;
    static const float angle = 2.0f * 3.1416f / circle_points;
        // this code (mostly) copied from question:
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    double angle1=0.0;
    glVertex2d(50 * cos(0.0) , 50 * sin(0.0));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<circle_points; i++)
    {       
        glVertex2d(50 * cos(angle1), 50 *sin(angle1));
        angle1 += angle;
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Main message loop
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAINWNDPROC FUNCTION
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static POINT mousepos;
    static float last_frame_time;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            HWND hWndLoading;
            PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
            int nBestMatch;
            // Show loading dialog box
            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
            hWndLoading = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_LOADING), hWnd, DummyProc);
            ShowWindow(hWndLoading, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            UpdateWindow(hWndLoading);

            // Get window DC
            hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

            // Set up the OpenGL pixel format for this window
            memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
            pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
            pfd.nVersion = 1;
            pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
            pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
            pfd.cColorBits = 32;
            pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
            nBestMatch = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
            SetPixelFormat(hDC, nBestMatch, &pfd);

            // Set up OpenGL
            hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
            wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
            OpenGL_Init();

            // Get rid of loading dialog
            SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW));
            DestroyWindow(hWndLoading);
            last_frame_time = GetTime();
            active = true;
            fovmode = FF_NORMAL;
            aspect = (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
            hfov = 90.0f;
            return 0;


        }

        case WM_ACTIVATE:
        {
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == WA_INACTIVE)
            {
                active = false;
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);      // Minimize when alt-tabbed away, since it's a fullscreen window
            }
            else
            {
                active = true;
                last_frame_time = GetTime();
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, false);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            if (active)
            {
                // Calculate time it took to draw last frame
                float current_time = GetTime();
                float frametime = current_time - last_frame_time;
                last_frame_time = current_time;
                // Handle input, logic, whatnot
                OpenGL_Logic(frametime);
                // Render the scene
                OpenGL_SetupView(fovmode);
                OpenGL_Render();
                // Flush and flip
                glFlush();
                SwapBuffers(hDC);
            }
            else
            {
                // If inactive, just rerender when we need to
                OpenGL_SetupView(fovmode);
                OpenGL_Render();
                glFlush();
                SwapBuffers(hDC);
                ValidateRect(hWnd, NULL);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        case WM_CHAR:
        {
            // Respond to keypresses
            switch (wParam)
            {
                // 'F' switches between preset fov modes
                case 'f':
                case 'F':
                {
                    ++fovmode;
                    if (fovmode == NUM_FOVMODES) fovmode = 0;

                    switch (fovmode)
                    {
                        case FF_NORMAL:     // Normal fov, full frame viewport
                        {
                            aspect = (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
                            hfov = 90.0f;
                            break;
                        }
                        case WS_WIDE:       // Wide fov with a widescreen viewport (aspect ratio of 2.35, same as theatre)
                        {
                            aspect = 2.35f;
                            hfov = 140.0f;
                            break;
                        }
                        case FF_WIDE:       // Wide fov with a full-frame viewport
                        {
                            aspect = (float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
                            hfov = 140.0f;
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'd':
                            {   
                                if (useLighting)
                                {
                                    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
                                }
                                glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
                                glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);
                                glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmb);
                                glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiff);
                                glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpec);
                                glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
                                if (useFog){
                                    glEnable(GL_FOG);
                                }
                                glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);
                                glFogfv(GL_FOG_INDEX, fogIndex);
                                glFogf(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_EXP);
                                glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.5);
                                glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 1.0);
                                glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 3.0);
                                glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
                                glCullFace(GL_BACK);
                                glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
                                glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
                                if (useLogo) {
                                }
                                else {
                                    glPolygonStipple((const GLubyte *) shadowPattern);
                                }

                                glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
                                glClearIndex(0);
                                glClearDepth(1);

                            }
                    break;
                }

                // Escape key exits
                case 27:
                {
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Make sure window is redrawn
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, false);

            return 0;
            }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            if (active)
            {
                // Capture mouse and hide cursor
                SetCapture(hWnd);
                ShowCursor(false);

                // Save off mouse position
                GetCursorPos(&mousepos);
            }

            return 0;
        }


        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            // Move view angles if dragging left button
            if (active && (wParam & MK_LBUTTON))
            {
                POINT pt;
                int deltax, deltay;
                bool wrap = false;

                // Get current mouse position
                GetCursorPos(&pt);

                // Calculate deltas
                deltax = pt.x - mousepos.x;
                deltay = pt.y - mousepos.y;

                // Wrap mouse position if needed
                if (pt.x == GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1)
                    pt.x = 0, wrap = true;
                else if (pt.x == 0)
                    pt.x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1, wrap = true;
                if (pt.y == GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1)
                    pt.y = 0, wrap = true;
                else if (pt.y == 0)
                    pt.y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1, wrap = true;
                if (wrap)
                    SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);

                // Save off new mouse position
                mousepos = pt;

                // Change view angles accordingly
                cam_yaw -= (float)deltax * MOUSE_CAMERA_ANGLE_FACTOR;
                cam_pitch -= (float)deltay * MOUSE_CAMERA_ANGLE_FACTOR;

                // Wrap yaw and clamp pitch
                if (cam_yaw > 360.0f) cam_yaw -= 360.0f;
                if (cam_yaw < 0.0f) cam_yaw += 0.0f;
                if (cam_pitch > 90.0f) cam_pitch = 90.0f;
                if (cam_pitch < -90.0f) cam_pitch = -90.0f;

                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, false);
            }

            return 0;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            if (active)
            {
                // Release mouse capture and show cursor
                ReleaseCapture();
                ShowCursor(true);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            // Shut down OpenGL
            wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(hRC);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should format your code, it's totally unreadable.

Comment: What's the point of `#include`ing the GLUT headers if you aren't using it?  Also, you might want to post the code that actually renders your scene if you want help with it.

Comment: @genpfault: He actually did post the code that "adds" the sun. In WinMain, erroneously assuming OpenGL was some kind of scene graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing API. You don't *"add"* objects, you **draw** them in the drawing routine. You just called a bunch of OpenGL drawing functions in the `WinMain` where they don't belong. Even if those had some effect (which they probably didn't) you'd see their result only shortly, namely until the next window redraw.

In the message handler in the WM_PAINT message some `OpenGL_*` functions are called. You must put your sun drawing code there/in one of those.